# Observing a threadsafe collection using the Reactive Framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, system.reactive

This will boil down to a fairly high level question.
I have a large dataset and need to validate each row (independently).
I want to use Parallel.Foreach, and call a validation method on that row. Assume this method to be threadsafe.
If the validation comes back with an error, I need to update the data row with this error.
I obviously can't do this from the background thread. I'm not sure what the best way to implement this error handling is, however.
My idea to implement this is to store the row IDs and errors in a BlockingCollection, since that is threadsafe for writing. Then I will constantly poll (from a background thread) and when the background thread finds data, invoke the form and update the current row.

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this, using the Reactive Framework? Basically, I need a multiple-producer threadsafe collection, that can be 'observed' upon and when a new value is added to the collection, the 'OnNext' would be executed on the main thread - is this possible? Ideally I could also control how often this happens (like only every 2-3 seconds, such that every 2-3 seconds the callback on the main thread would update multiple rows), so I am not constantly invoking the main thread.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't need to poll a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). The [Take Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) blocks until an item is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this strike your fancy:

```
IObservable<bool> ValidateAsync(Row item)
{
    return Observable.Start(() => {
        // TODO: Figure out if the row is valid
        return true;
    }, Scheduler.TaskPoolScheduler);
}

myBigDataTable.ToObservable()
    .Select(x => ValidateAsync(x).Select(y => new { Row = x, IsValid = y }))
    .Merge(10 /* rows concurrently */)
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current /*assuming WinForms */)
    .Subscribe(x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Row {0} validity: {1}", x.Row, x.IsValid);
    });
```

No locks, no silly containers, no blocking, 100% thread safe.

Comment: Small question - is there an extension I am missing to convert a DataTable object to an Observable?

Comment: Generally, anything IEnumerable can be converted to an IObservable - I'm not terribly familiar with DataTable though. Most of the extension methods you want live in `System.Reactive.Linq`